# how to update jsf 2 h:datatable by handle message cumming from cometd channle

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, cometd

i actually connected to a cometd channel which push a message from the server side.

i need to use this message to update my h:datatable

------------xhtml---------------------------

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new Object(); // or var map = {};


function getStatus(k) {
    return map[k];
}
        $(document).ready (function() {
         console.log("**** connect *****");
        cometd.handshake(isConnected);
        });
    function isConnected(handshakeReply){
        if (handshakeReply.successful){
            console.log("*** client connected ***");        
            cometd.subscribe('/user', handleMsg,isSubscribed); 

        }else{
            console.log("Connection Fail ");
        }
    }

    function isSubscribed(subscribeReply){
        if (subscribeReply.successful){
            console.log("***client subscribed ***");        
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }   
    function handlenMsg(message){
            console.log(message.data); 
            map=message.data;
    }

</script>

    <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{bean.orders}" var="o" 
                styleClass="table1" 
            >
                <h:column>              
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText id="Label" value="name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="nameOutput" value="#{o.name}">        
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText id="amountLabel" value="quantity" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText id="amountOutput" value="#{o.quantity}">

                </h:outputText>                 
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText id="statusLabel" value="status" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="ajax-loader.gif"/>
                    <h:outputText id="statusOutput" value="getStatus('key1'))" />
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton type="submit" id="button"

                value="submit"
                action="#{bean.doAction}"
                />
```

--------------------------- bean------------------

```
public class Bean {

    List<Order> orders;

public Bean ()
    {

        orders=new ArrayList<Order>();
        Order o= new Order();
        o.setName("key1");
        o.quantity("10");
        orders.add(o)
o= new Order();
        o.setName("key2");
        o.quantity("20");
        orders.add(o)

    }


public void doAction(List<Order> orders) {

        String channelName = "/user";
MarkedReference<ServerChannel> ref = bayeuxServer.createChannelIfAbsent(channelName, new ServerChannel.Initializer() {
            public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
                channel.setPersistent(true);
            }
        });
        ServerChannel channel = ref.getReference();
        String publishMesg = "";
        Order order;

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(
                orders.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {

            order = orderes.get(i);


            if (o.getName().equals("key1") {
                publishMesg =  " Success";
            } else {
                publishMesg =  " Fail";
            }

            data.put(o.getName(), publishMesg);

            channel.publish(session, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. The server-side Java code with CometD looks ok. The JSF code is rendered on the server-side, so the call to `getStatus()` cannot refer to the JavaScript function.

Comment: In order to render the JSF table on server-side you need to update some model bean on the server with the values you want to display. The implementation of `doAction()` just creates on-the-fly objects that are published.